# Close the form without errors

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a form with 3 different TextBoxes and 2 buttons -> Save and Close.
2 of the TextBoxes are invisible. 1 of these invisible TextBoxes is autoincrement integer and the second one has the value onLoad of the form. The last one is needed to fill.

**What I want:** When user clicks the button "Close" - the form will close, even if visible TextBox is empty. 

**What I has now:** When user clicks "Close" button - access goes with the error "Text box is empty".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are wanting to control the saving of records.  But at the same time, I think you have the `Record Source` of the form set to something.  The below demonstrates how you can control the saving of records yourself:

I have the following form in design view:

[image]

In regular view it looks like the following:

[image]

I set the `Record Source` on the form to nothing.

The names of the 3 text boxes for this demonstration are: `txtField1`, `txtField2`, and `txtField3`

Here is the code behind the form:

```
Private Sub cmdSave_Click()
  If (Len(txtField3 & "") <> 0) Then
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO yyy (Field2, Field3) " & _
                 "VALUES ('" & txtField2 & "', '" & txtField3 & "')"
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

    MsgBox "You have successfully saved the record.", , "SUCCESS"
  Else
    MsgBox "You must provide a value for Field 3 " & _
           "before saving the record." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
           "The record was not saved.", , "MISSING INFORMATION"
  End If
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Load()
  txtField2 = "test"
End Sub


Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
  On Error GoTo Err_cmdClose_Click
  DoCmd.Close
Exit_cmdClose_Click:
  Exit Sub
Err_cmdClose_Click:
  MsgBox Err.Description
  Resume Exit_cmdClose_Click
End Sub
```

When the form opens up `txtField2` is automatically given a value.  When the user clicks on the `Save` button the code checks to see if they entered a value in `txtField3`.  If they did then the `INSERT` statement is executed and a message stating the record was successfully saved is displayed.  If they did not enter a value into `txtField3` then a message is displayed saying they cannot save the record until they provide a value.

Since the `Record Source` of the form is not set you will have no problem closing the form.

Actually, for the `AutoNumber` field you don't even need a text box for that.  As you can see in my above example I don't pass that in the `INSERT` statement.  The database will handle that for you.